# requests.auth.AuthBase TypeError on call

Tags: python, python-requests

From the docs at https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/

I gathered that the `__call__` function in my own Auth Class should have the r argument,

However when i go to call this class in requests.get(auth=MyClass), I get the error `TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'r'`

The code for my class can be found here https://pastebin.com/YDZ2DeaT

```
import requests
import time
import base64

from requests.auth import AuthBase

class TokenAuth(AuthBase):
    """Refreshes SkyKick token, for use with all Skykick requests"""
    def __init__(self, Username: str, SubKey: str):
        self.Username = Username
        self.SubKey = SubKey
    
    # Initialise with no token and instant expiry
        self.Token = None
        self.TokenExpiry = time.time()
    

        self.Headers = {
            # Request headers

            'Content-Type'             : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': self.SubKey,

        }

        self.Body = {
        # Request body
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'scope'     : 'Partner'
        }

    def regenToken(self):
    # Sends request to regenerate token
        try:
        # Get key from API
            response = requests.post("https://apis.skykick.com/auth/token",
                                     headers=self.Headers,
                                     auth=(self.Username, self.SubKey),
                                     data=self.Body,
                                     ).json()
        except: 
            raise Exception("Sending request failed, check connection.")

        # API errors are inconsistent, easiest way to catch them
        if "error" in response or "statusCode" in response:
            raise Exception(
                "Token requesting failed, cannot proceed with any Skykick actions, exiting.\n"
                f"Error raised was {response}")

    # Get token from response and set expiry
        self.Token = response["access_token"]
        self.TokenExpiry = time.time() + 82800

    def __call__(self, r):
    
    # If token expiry is now or in past, call regenToken
        if self.TokenExpiry <= time.time():
            self.regenToken()
    # Set headers and return complete requests.Request object
        r.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {self.Token}"
        return r

# Initialise our token class, so it is ready to call
TokenClass = TokenAuth("test", "1234")

#Send request with class as auth method.
requests.get("https://apis.skykick.com/whoami", auth=TokenClass())
```

I've tried using the example code, which works, but I can't figure out why mine won't work.

python-requests version is 2.25.1

Comment: If I make a blank Request object, and pass it into the request, it works,
`r = requests.Request()
response = requests.get("https://apis.skykick.com/whoami", auth=TokenClass(r))
Traceback`
This is different to how the docs show usage though.

Comment: `TokenClass = TokenAuth("test", "1234")`  You seem to be creating an object from a class, and calling that object, and passing that in.  Shouldn't you just be passing in an instance of `TokenClass`?

Comment: @Alex028502 I'm not exactly sure what the difference is, do you mean doing requests.get(auth=TokenAuth("test","1234")) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what is going on.

This line instantiates an object, called `TokenClass`

```
TokenClass = TokenAuth("test", "1234")
```

then here,

```
requests.get("https://apis.skykick.com/whoami", auth=TokenClass())
```

you are calling that object like a function

when you call an object like a function, python looks for the `__call__` method of the object.

And you are not calling in any arguments here.  What you have is roughly the same as this I think

```
requests.get("https://apis.skykick.com/whoami", auth=TokenClass.__call__())
```

and so it complains that you are missing the `r` argument

---

This is their example:

```
import requests
class MyAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __call__(self, r):
        # Implement my authentication
        return r

url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'
requests.get(url, auth=MyAuth())
```

`MyAuth` is a class that they define, and then `MyAuth()` creates an instance of it that they pass in to `get`.

Yours is more like this

```
import requests
class MyAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __call__(self, r):
        # Implement my authentication
        return r

url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'

myAuth = MyAuth() # create an instance of the class

requests.get(url, auth=myAuth()) # call the instance and pass in result
```

It could also be written like this

```
import requests
class MyAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __call__(self, r):
        # Implement my authentication
        return r

url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'


requests.get(url, auth=MyAuth()())
```

This program with produce the same error you are getting

```
import requests
class MyAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __call__(self, r):
        # Implement my authentication
        return r

url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'

MyAuth()()
```

because when you put `()` after a class, you get an instance, and when you put `()` after an instance, you call the `__call__` method

Comment: You can see at the bottom of https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/ that this is how it's meant to be called, the r argument is I believe supposed to be passed through by the requests module

Comment: I see, my way relies on the object existing to hold the token and expiry, so I suppose the easiest way is to create my own Request object and use that, or store the token and find a way to quickly retrieve.

Thanks for the insight!

Comment: No.  The object exists when you instantiate it inline requests.get(url, auth=MyAuth())
To unstand better you sould change their example to two lines
`myAuth=MyAuth(); requests.get(url, auth=myAuth)`

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to make it exist twice, and but the first time, you use a give the object you create a class's name (starting with an upper case letter), but it is really an object, and can just be passed in as is

Comment: Oh I see now!

That's working for me now thank you very much! +1